# where to throw the HTTP Runtime Exception

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have the following runtime exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
public class ExpectationsFailedException extends RuntimeException {
    public ExpectationsFailedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

My question is if it is ok to throw the previous HTTP exception in my service layer or should I throw it from my controller:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    ...

    public void addUser(final String email, final String username, final String password){
        if(parameters_are_not_valid){
           throw new ExpectationsFailedException("Invalid input");
        }
    }

}
```

The controller exception throwing solution would be the following:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    ...

    public void addUser(final String email, final String username, final String password) throws InvalidInputParameters {
        if(parameters_are_not_valid){
           throw new InvalidInputParameters("Invalid input");
        }
    }

}
```

and in my controller

```
@RestController
public class XController{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpForm form, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            throw new ExpectationsFailedException("Input parameters conditions were not fulfilled");
        }

        try {
            userService.addUser(...);
        }
        catch(InvalidInputParameters ex){
            throw new ExpectationsFailedException("Invalid service input parameters");
        }
    }
}
```

Which of those solutions is preferred? Why? I have a feeling that I should not throw HTTP exceptions in my services because I may use that services in other contexts which may not be related to HTTP.

I would go with the second one.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your last statement. Your service layer should be independent of HTTP or frontent frameworks (`@ResponseStatus` is Spring MVC annotation and therefore it's not the best practice to use it in your service layer).

However you don't have to throw one exception in service layer, catch it in controller and rethrow another exception annotated with `@ResponseStatus`. Just add exception handler for the service exception and return appropriate response status from it. You have plenty of options, for instance [`@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html):

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidInputParameters.class)
public void handle() {
    // Do nothing, just return the status
}
```

You can put this code to [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotated class to enable it for all controllers or just in you controller if it's not needed elsewhere.